# How to add a new column with labels in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis, nltk

I have thousands of sentences that I would need to label based on their sentiment. 
An example is

```
Testo
"Può dirmi quale fotocamera della Sony fa delle belle foto?"
"Che macchina fantastica! Ha smesso di funzionare dopo due giorni"
"Quel pallavolista ha un fisico pauroso"
"Questo iPad è fantastico"
```

I have tried using Fasttext (Python Package) but I do not know how to add the sentiment label in a new column. Also, I got the wrong sentiment (below it is shown the expected output).

```
Testo                                                            Sentiment
"Può dirmi quale fotocamera della Sony fa delle belle foto?"         0
"Che macchina fantastica! Ha smesso di funzionare dopo due giorni"  -1
"Quel pallavolista ha un fisico pauroso"                             1
"Questo iPad è fantastico"                                           1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you already have a trained model to classify sentiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a working method to get the sentiment label for an individual sentence?

If so, I would think you could just create a method to get the sentiment given a sentence and use it's return value as the row entry.

The apply function from pandas will apply a function to every row if you specify axis=1

```
def getSentiment(row):
    # Do some sentiment operations here on row['Testo']
    return sentiment_label

df.apply(getSentiment, axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you @Sean Payne. May I ask you if you suggest to get the sentiment building some rules from scratch or just using some already existing tool in python (what you should suggest)?

Comment: I'm not as sure about the sentiment labeling. I'm guessing there has been a ton done in that field though as the Twitter sentiment labeling is a popular beginner exercise, so consider doing some more Google searching to look for an existing method.